# How to change the "." separator used by plyr generate names

Tags: r, plyr

The variables used to split the data.frame in the d_ply function family are then merged using the separator "." to produce names for the resulting list in case of dlply, e.g.

```
library(plyr)
res <- data.frame(id1= rep("a.x",3),id2=c("a","b","c"),
       val =  c(1,2,3),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Which gives the data.frame

```
> res
  id1 id2 val
1 a.x   a   1
2 a.x   b   2
3 a.x   c   3
```

Then when running dlply the following names are generated

```
> names(plyr::dlply(res, .(id1, id2), function(x){x$val}))
[1]  "a.x.a" "a.x.b" "a.x.c"
```

Is there a way to change the separator used by plyr to for instance "|" ?

Comment: Could you just change the names yourself? `colnames(x) <- gsub('.', '|', colnames(x), fixed = TRUE)` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did arrive at the following solution:

```
> names(xx) <- apply(attributes(xx)$split_labels,1 ,paste , collapse="|")
> names(xx)
[1] "a.x|a" "a.x|b" "a.x|c"
```